# Get xaml origin by klicking or selecting text in document viewer!

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, documentviewer

I'm trying to find the XPS xaml origin of an (text) element which is klicked or selected in a document viewer. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have the anwser: and it's really easy too, suscribe to the mouse move or some mouse event, and cast the original source to either: glyph, canvas or path! That's it folks